# i keep getting this error Error: Could not find or load main class javaclass.Javaclass

Tags: java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Javaclass;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * t
 * 
 * @author dhayal
 */
public class Javaclass {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, n;
        System.out.println("enter the value");
        n = a.nextInt();
        while (n > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
                // TODO code application logic here
            }
            System.out.println();
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WhAT is the fileName of your `.java` program???

Comment: how are you compiling your program? And why do you have package name same as class name?

Comment: @Webby- It happens in case of IDE's like NEtBeasn,Eclipse. They by default provide this setting of placing of file...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run this by:

```
java javaclass/Javaclass
```

try

```
java Javaclass/Javaclass
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

When you compile using `javac Javaclass.java` the resulting `Javaclass.class` will be created in the same folder so if you run the class using either `java Javaclass.Javaclass` or `java Javaclass` you will get `Could not find or load main class Javaclass.Javaclass`.

What you have to do is when compiling the source you have to mention the target folder using `-d` option as follows

```
javac -d . Javaclass.java
```

In this case the Javaclass will be compiled and the resulting class fill will be placed as `./Javaclass/Javaclass.class`

Then you can run the class using following command.

```
java Javaclass.Javaclass
```